# Dispersion relation with $(F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu})^2$ correction

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, fourier-transform, variational-calculus, effective-field-theory

This is in context of [this paper by Nima et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0602178) where they derive positivity bounds using dispersion relations. Specifically, deriving the EOM from equation $(1)$ in the paper $$L=-\frac{1}{4}F^2+\frac{c_1}{\Lambda^4}F^4+\frac{c_2}{\Lambda^4}(F\tilde{F})^2$$ and going to momentum space, which should yield eq. $(12)$ in the paper
$$k^\mu k_\mu+32\frac{c_1}{\Lambda^4}(F^{\mu\nu}k_\mu\epsilon_\nu)^2+32\frac{c_2}{\Lambda^4}(\tilde{F}k_\mu\epsilon_\nu)^2$$

I have trouble deriving this. Shouldn't the EOM, in the Lorenz gauge, be $$\partial^2A_\mu+32\frac{c_1}{\Lambda^4}F^2\partial^2A_\mu+32\frac{c_2}{\Lambda^4}(F\tilde{F})\partial^2A_\mu=0$$

From here, we expand about some nontrivial background, say $A_{\mu}=A^{(0)}_\mu+a_\mu$ where $\partial_\mu A^{(0)}_\nu=c_{\mu\nu}$ for some constant tensor $c$, and then linearizing and expanding $a_\mu$ in plane waves doesn't give me equation (12), as should be obvious from the EOM I write above(unless I have derived it incorrectly somehow). What am I missing here? Any leads would be appreciated.